# Inverse with respect to a given circle

Tags: real-analysis, circles, inversive-geometry

> Determine the inverse with respect to a given circle $g:\mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{+}, g(x,y)=x^{2}+y^{2}$.

I have looked around for non geometric derivations without finding any of value. Anyone willing to lend a helping hand?

Comment: This is not an injective function (not 1-1), so $g^{-1}$ is not a function. For example, $g^{-1}(1)$ contains every pair $(\pm t,\pm\sqrt{1-t^2})$ for $0\leq t\leq 1$ (with all combinations of sign indicated). By $\mathbb R^+$ you must necessarily mean $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: a circle of radius $r$ is the set $(r \cos(\alpha), r \sin(\alpha))$. does this help?

Comment: @mm-aops I am looking for a place where I can find a derivation for the result which figures here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleInverseCurve.html and here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431652/how-to-calculate-the-inverse-of-a-point-with-respect-to-a-circle?rq=1 without the use of a geometric argument.

Comment: so you don't mean 'inverse' in the sense 'inverse of a function' but 'inverse' in the geometric meaning, i.e. inverse with respect to a given circle. you should probably include it in the body of the question cause it seems a bit amigous the way it's written

Comment: @mm-aops Thanks for the suggestion, I have changed the question accordingly.

Comment: $g$ is not a circle.  Which circle do you mean?